# How to Detect if a program is runging on a Full- Screen mode

Tags: c#, monitor

Is there any way to detect program that is running on a full screen mode ? but using event watcher.

Ive done a lot of other codes but none of them work good and all of them need some timer or a lot of using...

With using i mean a lot!!! and this is the problem.

This is the start of the program :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT rc);
```

Here is the function that runs in the Timer :

```
//Detect if the current app is running in full screen
bool runningFullScreen = false;
RECT appBounds;
Rectangle screenBounds;
IntPtr hWnd;

//get the dimensions of the active window
hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
if (hWnd!=null && !hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    //Check we haven't picked up the desktop or the shell
    if (!(hWnd.Equals(desktopHandle) || hWnd.Equals(shellHandle)))
    {
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, out appBounds);
        //determine if window is fullscreen
        screenBounds = Screen.FromHandle(hWnd).Bounds;
        if ((appBounds.Bottom - appBounds.Top) == screenBounds.Height && (appBounds.Right - appBounds.Left) == screenBounds.Width)
        {
            runningFullScreen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem of this is that i need to use Timer or bgWorker and this is not a very good like for the work of it.

Comment: What is "full screen mode"? An application having a maximized window? What if multiple applications have a maximized window? What if there are multiple monitors - is it satisfying for your analysis if only one of them has a/any maximized window? Maybe it would be a good idea to describe the actual problem, i.e. why you need to know the information you seek.

Comment: No something like when you start movie or game something like that .

Comment: So the question would be "how do I detect if a (movie | game) is running?". Sorry, but I'm still confused as to what you're up to.

Comment: i need to make a program that is in conslole of romethign like that and when i start my game or movie to write in the console on this time i start a movie or game i done this module but the problem is with the detection of the window or game

Comment: If you don't want to use a timer then you'll need to ask to operating system to provide you with an event when the window size or position changes.  That's possible, [use this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Or just about any UI Automation library so you don't have to write the pinvoke yourself.

Comment: ok but is there a way to do this i n C#